# Use a raw_input to specify a specific file to create a copy of it's back up and change the file names of the back up and original file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working to set up a process that creates a new file from a backup file that is already in a folder. My program currently works, but I would like to eliminate as much of the user input as possible, so that all you have to do is enter the filename that just crashed on you and watch the program do the rest. I am fairly new at python and have been having trouble figuring out a way to get that initial raw_input to be the basis for the rest of the program to run off. I have uploaded the code that I have which currently does the job, so any tips that would help me make this code better would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
import os
import copy
import shutil

def copy_vrb():
    #Creates a copy of a specific "Filename.vrb" which gets renamed to "Filename_COPY.vrb"
    oldvrb=raw_input("Enter the .vr filename you were working on before it crashed: ") # With file extension
    newvrb=raw_input("Rename the new .vrb file to Filename_COPY")
    shutil.copy(oldvrb, newvrb + ".vrb") # Without file extension
copy_vrb()

def file_rename():
    # Takes original "Filename.vr" that crashed, and changes the filename to "Filename_BAD.vr".
    oldname=raw_input("Enter the Filename.vr that you were working on before it crashed: ") # With file extension
    newname=raw_input("Rename the file as Filename_BAD")
    os.rename(oldname, newname + ".vr")
file_rename()

def rename_copy():
    # Renames Filename_COPY.vrb to Filename_NEW.vr
    oldname=raw_input("Enter the Filename_COPY.vrb: ") # With file extension
    newname=raw_input("Rename to Filename_NEW: ") # Without file extension
    os.rename(oldname, newname, +".vr")
rename_copy()
```

In my data folder that I would work out of, I have multiple pairs of files, (10001.vr(the file that would crash), and 10001.vrb(the backup that is created when I open the file in VR Mapping) What I want is to be able to input the specific file that crashed.

1. Create a copy of the 10001.vrb file ---> 10001_COPY.vrb
2. Change the 10001.vr file ---> 10001_BAD.vr
3. Lastly change the 10001_COPY.vrb file into the new usable file ---> 10001_NEW.vr

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is you accept the name of file as a command line input instead of doing raw_input(). 
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

```
import os
import copy
import shutil

def copy_vrb(oldvrb):
    newvrb = os.path.splitext(oldvrb)[0] + "_COPY" 
    shutil.copy(oldvrb, newvrb + ".vrb") # Without file extension


oldvrb=raw_input("Enter the .vr filename you were working on before it crashed: ") 
copy_vrb(oldvrb)
```

And then you do the rest for the other functions.

Comment: Thank you for the help, with this I was able to shorten the process from 6 input steps to 3 input steps, my ultimate goal is to be able to define the specific .vr and .vrb files once then have the program produce the duplicate files. . Also I am not too sure how to run that function in main. Would I just def main(): at the beginning of the script then end with the if __name__ == '__main__': at the end? Thank you again for the help

Comment: I realized I was being a bit unclear. Technically speaking, the way the code is it is in main. This is a good article if you want to learn a bit more about "special variable names" https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__name__-special-variable-python/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that makes more sense now and is being run directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Just a matter of merging your functions - perhaps:

```
import os
import shutil

def recover_vrb():
    vr_file = raw_input("Enter the .vr filename you were working on before it crashed: ") # With file extension

    vr_name = vr_file.split('.')[0]

    vrb_file = vr_name + '.vrb'
    moved_vr_file = vr_name + '_BAD.vr'
    os.rename(vr_file, moved_vr_file)
    shutil.copy(vrb_file, vr_file)
```

Comment: I like what this is doing, but I am running into an error when trying to get it to produce a _NEW.vr file. The error I am getting is "in copyfile raise Error(" '%s' and '%s' are the same file" % (src, dst)). So for instance if I enter 40035.vr in the first prompt I get the program to spit out 40035_BAD.vr then that error.   I have tried duplicating your function code to below as def recover_vr(): but that isn't working for me, I have also tried adding another moved_vr_file = vrb_name + '_NEW.vr' and have the same result.

Comment: You're right, I had an error - see my quick revision.